# How can I find the position of each digit in a string?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string for example:

```
12abc3def4
```

How can I get the position of each single digit in that string using regular expressions?

expected output:

```
Digit: Position
"1": 0
"2": 1
"3": 5
"4": 9
```

**Edit:**

So I was told finding the position is not possible with regex. Now I will need to find the digits in the string, then look up their position. The problem is that I am using the following regex:

```
preg_match('/[\d*]/', "12abc3def4", $output)
```

It is possible a digit appears more than once, or never appears. It is also possible that the string doesn't have any digit.

But it is only giving me the first digit which is "1", and stops there.

Comment: 1. a regex is overkill for this: a simple "index of character in string" method will be better. 2. What have you tried?

Comment: I thought regex was the best solution for such problems. I was hoping to do something like this: preg_match('/[\d*]/', "12abc3def4", $output) but the output is only showing the first digit "1" and ignoring the rest. Let alone I don't know if it can give me the position.

Comment: @Lamar Add ^^ this code to your question and show where you are stuck

Comment: @Rizier123 Not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: I don't know which digits are there if there were any. I need to use regex first so that I can find which digits are found.

Comment: @Lamar Add the code from the comment above into your question and show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @Lamar People down vote you because basically, elements called "position of character" is not  exist in regex concept. and to count the position using regex is also impossible. Unless you use build-in function in php to check it.

Comment: @Lamar is it possible for the same digit to appear twice or more in the string?

Comment: @terces907 Thank you for clarifying. However, a simple comment such as yours can give me the answer which I didn't know before. Anyway, I still have the problem in which only the first digit is showing in the output. I'm including the code in the original question. Thanks again.

Comment: @Lamar `'/[\d*]/g'` put `g` as modifier should be help. It will give you all matches.

Comment: @terces907 There is no `g` modifier in php

Comment: Sorry, I just check it from some regex tester for php, it provides me this modifier @Lamar please check this http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php.

Comment: "g" did not work for me, but thanks anyway. I'm going with the solution of looping over string chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can [access a string like an array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr), just simply loop through the string and if it is a digit print the position, e.g.

```
<?php

    $str = "12abc3def4";

    echo "Digit | Position<br>";
    for($i = 0, $length = strlen($str); $i < $length; $i++) {
        if(is_numeric($str[$i]))
            echo $i . " | " . $str[$i] . "<br>";
    }

?>
```

output:

```
Digit | Position
    0 | 1
    1 | 2
    5 | 3
    9 | 4
```

Comment: @Lamar You're welcome. Also see the other answers which also show different ways to archive this. (BTW: Did you noticed how the upV's go up after you showed some effort in the question ?! <- Always show your effort/attempt(s). So that nobody feels like he just does the work for you)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) with flag `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`

```
$str = "12abc3def4";

if(preg_match_all('/\d/', $str, $out, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)!==false)
  print_r($out[0]);
```

`\d` matches a digit `[0-9]`; See [test at eval.in](https://eval.in/420929)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 9
        )

)
```

Comment: Just to append this here and make it even more clear: `First element` is the `digit`, `second element` is the `position` in the subArrays.

Comment: I love answers that showcase practical uses for lesser-known features :)

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string with into an array with [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and filter it with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

The original array indices, indicating the positions of each character, are retained:

```php
$str = '12abc3def4';

$filtered = array_filter(str_split($str), function($ch) {
    return ctype_digit($ch); // return `true` for `integer` only
});

print_r($filtered);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [5] => 3
    [9] => 4
)
```

To better reflect your example output, just `var_dump(array_flip($filtered));`:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 9
)
```

Hope this helps :)